# On Heroku, Cedar, with Unicorn: Getting ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, unicorn

Heroku support says this has to do with their version of libssl on shared databases, but we've encountered it on a project that's on a dedicated database, too.

Basically this error happens every so often (closer to just after a deploy) on every project we've moved to the new Cedar stack with Unicorn configured to 3 workers:

Error Message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.at

Where:
some_controller#index
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb, line 505
```

No answers from heroku yet besides maybe wait who knows how long for us to upgrade our shared database servers* and I haven't found anything on google.

They also suggested it has to do with unicorn's workers overlapping and that we should switch to Thin but the performance gain is well worth the occasional error(I think!). I'm hoping there's a way to configure Unicorn to prevent the overlap.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, what have you done to resolve it? Thanks!

*not their actual words, just how I felt after their response.

Comment: were those the exact words from their support team? If so, that's very unprofessional...

Comment: I got the same errors. I'm using unicorn with 3 workers.

Comment: No, it was not their actual words, just how they made me feel: not sure WHEN it will update and it might not fix the problem. They said we should try a dedicated DB, but we see the same errors on an app we /do/ have on dedicated.

Comment: For future reference, this error started happening to us after we added `preload_app true` to unicorn.rb.

Comment: Yea, and preload_app true is required for the New Relic addon

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Heroku support suggested that I add this to my Unicorn config:

**Append** to your `config/unicorn.rb`:

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 
  end
end
```

I added it and we haven't seen a single `PGError: SSL SYSCALL` error all day.

Comment: Worked for me too. I also think my problem started when I introduced New Relic and the `preload app true` option. This seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! Was just about to open a support ticket with Heroku.