# Am I preloading the app in Heroku + Unicorn correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

When using Unicorn on Heroku. Scaling up, will have problems, since the newly scaled web dyno's can be accessed by a request when it is still loading the app. Which mostly results in a Timeout error.

I did a bit of reading at http://codelevy.com/2010/02/09/getting-started-with-unicorn.html and https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn

The two articles suggested using `preload_app true`. And an `after_fork` and `before_fork` block.

In Rails 3+, is the code in the `before_block` still required? I read somewhere, otherwise. Anyone who has experienced setting this up before and would like to share?

Am I missing anything else? Am I pre-loading the app correctly?

```
# config/initializers/unicorn.rb
# Read from:
# http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/01-more-concurrency-on-a-single-heroku-dyno-with-the-new-celadon-cedar-stack/
worker_processes 3 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
timeout 30         # restarts workers that hang for 90 seconds

# Noted from http://codelevy.com/2010/02/09/getting-started-with-unicorn.html
# and https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn
preload_app true

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  ##
  # When sent a USR2, Unicorn will suffix its pidfile with .oldbin and
  # immediately start loading up a new version of itself (loaded with a new
  # version of our app). When this new Unicorn is completely loaded
  # it will begin spawning workers. The first worker spawned will check to
  # see if an .oldbin pidfile exists. If so, this means we've just booted up
  # a new Unicorn and need to tell the old one that it can now die. To do so
  # we send it a QUIT.
  #
  # Using this method we get 0 downtime deploys.

  old_pid = Rails.root + '/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin'
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing here is expected.  The moment you scale up by a dyno, the Heroku platform will deploy that slug to a new dyno, which is entirely isolated from your other dynos (i.e another unicorn master).

Once that dyno is deployed and running (effectively booted), the routing mesh will start sending requests to that dyno, which is when Rails will start up on the Unicorn, or whatever, server you've got setup.

However, once that request arrives you have a 30 second window to return your data or the request will be timed out on the routing mesh (error H12).

Therefore, to summarize, your problem isn't to do with forking, it's that your application cannot start up within 30 seconds, hence the early timeouts.  Worrying about forking and PID files is that not something that you need to worry about on Heroku platform.

Comment: Hi Neil. The solution is to preload the app, to prevent requests from coming in until the dyno (unicorn master) loads the app fully. My concern here is whether I need the code in the `before_fork` block?

Comment: Your before_fork will be achieving nothing.  As I said before, the problem lies in the fact that the Heroku routing mesh will be sending you requests before your Unicorn has started.  Preloading the application will not resolve this.

Comment: If that is the case. How does one prevent timeout errors from occurring when spinning / scaling up new web dynos on Heroku?

Comment: Spinning up inside 30 seconds is the only way.

Comment: That's not acceptable as requests will DEFINITELY timeout. Which can cause a web dyno to re-spawn continuously, creating more timeout errors

Comment: Incorrect.  The request is timed out on the routing mesh, NOT the dyno grid, so even after your request is timed out, the dyno will still be starting up in the background, so the second request will hit a ready dyno.

Comment: If you are saying the second request will hit a ready dyno, then why are requests hitting newly spawned web dynos when they should be hitting a ready dyno?

Comment: I'm talking in the context of one dyno.  The routing mesh does not care about the dyno states, only that there are some to fire requests at.  If you have some ready dynos, the routing mesh will fire requests at them regardless of the state of Unicorn.  This is standard load balancing.

Comment: If there is nothing we can do about these timeout errors, occurring at spawn. Is this behavior normal then on Heroku? How do we explain this to our clients? Not too many end-users will be happy about this

Comment: This isn't very helpful. It appears that when you are using Thin, Heroku waits until the new dyno server is ready before firing requests at it. With Unicorn, it sends the requests before Unicorn is ready, hence the request takes more than 30 seconds, and Heroku unhelpfully kills it. There must be a way to fix this for Unicorn.

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer but I were able to reduce these nasty scaling timeouts with this Unicorn configuration:

```
worker_processes 3 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
timeout 30         # restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds
preload_app true

# hack: traps the TERM signal, preventing unicorn from receiving it and performing its quick shutdown.
# My signal handler then sends QUIT signal back to itself to trigger the unicorn graceful shutdown
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/9996949/235297
before_fork do |_server, _worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end
end

# Fix PostgreSQL SSL error
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513432/235297
after_fork do |server, worker| 
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and 
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 
end
```

Also, I use `heroku labs:enable preboot` (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot/). Unfortunately, I still see some timeouts when scaling up the web dynos.

Here's a discussion in the HireFire support forum, I initiated: http://hirefireapp.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/205-scaling-up-and-down-too-quickly-provoking-503s

Comment: Following the same approach and it isn't helping. It seems that even with preload there is a delay between when Unicorn starts "listening" and when the forked workers are "ready", for me this is >30s so even with all that *and* preboot I get H12 errors.

Answer (score 2):

`preload_app true` helped for our app, so do give it a shot if you're seeing issues with timeouts during deploy/reboot. The comments saying it doesn't help made me think it wasn't worth trying, then realised it was indeed the fix we needed.

Our situation was a slow-to-boot Rails app using [preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot). On some deploys and restarts, we would get a lot of timeouts, to the point that the site was considered down by our uptime monitoring.

We came to realise that with `preload_app false`, Unicorn will bind its port first and then load the app. As soon as it binds the port, Heroku starts sending it traffic. But it then takes a looong time for this slow app to load, so that traffic gets timeouts.

This is easy to verify by running Unicorn in dev, trying to access the site right after starting Unicorn, and checking whether you get a "no server on that port" type error (desirable) or a very slow request (not desirable).

When we instead set `preload_app true`, then it would take longer until Unicorn binds the port, but once it does and Heroku sends it traffic, it's ready to respond.