# How can I tell unicorn to understand Heroku's signals?

Tags: ruby, heroku, signals, unicorn

Perhaps you've seen this...

```
2012-03-07T15:36:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2012-03-07T15:36:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-03-07T15:36:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> Process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-03-07T15:36:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

This is a well known problem when running [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) on [heroku](http://heroku.com)...

- [heroku uses SIGTERM for graceful shutdown](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps)
- [unicorn uses SIGTERM for quick shutdown](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html)

Can I tell heroku to send `SIGQUIT`? Or can I tell unicorn to treat `SIGTERM` as graceful shutdown?

Comment: I didin't know that. I was considering unicorn for a project but this makes me reconsider. Here are the signals that thin uses: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/server.rb#L211 In both cases, QUIT signals a graceful shutdown, but INT and TERM are swapped.

Comment: BTW, there's another factor here -- heroku will send TERM to the process defined in the Procfile, but then that process is responsible for handing the signal down as it sees fit. So if you are running your server behind bundle exec, even if heroku was sending the correct signal you would see the behavior above because the webserver doesn't get the signal at all. I've talked to support about this and they are coming up with a solution.

Comment: I found this today, I haven't explored it yet: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Custom-Signals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a hack, but I've successfully created a unicorn config file that traps the `TERM` signal, preventing unicorn from receiving it and performing its quick shutdown. My signal handler then sends `QUIT` signal back to itself to trigger the unicorn graceful shutdown.

Tested with Ruby 1.9.2, Unicorn 4.0.1 and 4.2.1, Mac OS X.

```
listen 9292
worker_processes 1

# This is a hack.  The code is run with 'before_fork' so it runs
# *after* Unicorn installs its own TERM signal handler (which makes
# this highly dependent on the Unicorn implementation details).
#
# We install our own signal handler for TERM and simply re-send a QUIT
# signal to our self.
before_fork do |_server, _worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end
end
```

One concern is that (I believe) this signal handler is inherited by worker processes.  But, the worker process installs its own `TERM` handler, which should overwrite this one, so I would not expect any issue.  (See `Unicorn::HttpServer#init_worker_process @ lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:551`.

Edit: one more detail, this block that installs the signal handler will run once per worker process (because `before_fork`), but this merely redundant and won't affect anything.

Comment: this is the accepted answer because Patrick came up with it years b4 heroku did... but see Clay's answer for the latest authoritative answer

Answer (score 9):

Heroku now provides instruction for this here:
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/27/unicorn_rails

Their suggested unicorn.rb file is:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes 3
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```