# Rails + Heroku + Sidekiq = PG::Error: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have a rails app that uses Sidekiq's DelayMailer to send mails asynchronously. That app is deployed on heroku where we use PG for our DB. The EOF error (PG::Error: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected) appears (not every time) in methods of my implementation of ActionMailer. 
Errors seem to appear when I'm trying to access the DB from ActionMailer methods.

```
def new_message(user_id, message_id)
  @user = User.find user_id # ERROR appears here when trying to access the DB
...
```

I have no clue on what's going on. And I have googled for the solution and I only found some advice on adding after_fork and before_fork to unicorn.rb which I already have and I'm not sure if that's even related.

Comment: See also [Postgres + Heroku SSL SYSCALL error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497039/on-heroku-cedar-with-unicorn-getting-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror) and [On Heroku, Cedar, with Unicorn: Getting ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497039/on-heroku-cedar-with-unicorn-getting-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror) even if you're not on Heroku.

Comment: Just btw, the problem resolved itself. So I don't know what exactly was wrong. I'm guessing there was something wrong on heroku.