# Forcing new database connection when SSL SYSCALL error and CONN_MAX_AGE > 0

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, celery

Using Django 1.7 and Celery on Heroku with Postgres and RabbitMQ.

I recently set the [`CONN_MAX_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#conn-max-age) setting in Django to `60` or so so I could start pooling database connections. This worked fine until I discovered a problem where if for any reason a database connection was killed, Celery would continue using the bad database connection, consuming tasks but immediately throwing the following error within each task:

```
OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor
```

I would like to keep pooling database connections, but this has happened a few times now and I obviously can't allow Celery to randomly fail. **How can I get Django (or Celery) to force a new database connection *only* when this error is hit?**

(Alternatively, another idea I had was to force the Celery worker to run with a modified `settings.py` that sets `CONN_MAX_AGE=0` only for Celery... but that feels very much like the wrong way to do it.)

> Please note that this StackOverflow question seems to solve the problem on Rails, but I haven't found an equivalent for Django:
>   [On Heroku, Cedar, with Unicorn: Getting ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497039/on-heroku-cedar-with-unicorn-getting-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tracked it down to a combination of `CONN_MAX_AGE` and `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD`. At that point it became obvious that it must be something to do with Celery not closing connections properly when a worker is replaced and from that I found this bug report: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2453

Upgrading to Celery 3.1.18 seems to have solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  What do you have `CONN_MAX_AGE` and `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` set to?

Comment: None (meaning db connections live forever) and 20 (I find if a worker is left running forever and processes an array of different tasks it ends up importing tons of libraries and consuming loads of RAM even for tiny tasks). The Django ORM isn't thread/process safe so Celery has to close and reopen new connections inside every new worker and this bug was caused by that not occurring correctly.